# Spring 4.1.6 application context initialisation getting failed

Tags: java, spring

I'am trying to upgrade my legacy spring web application from 3.1 to 4.1.6.RELEASE.
I'am facing the following exception.

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
failed java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;
from class
org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster
    at
org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.setBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:84)
    at
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.<init>(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:60)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:667)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:471)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) May 22, 2015 11:01:07 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

Comment: You probably have a mix of jars from different versions of Spring in the classpath.

Comment: please add the `caused by `part also

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; in my case it was a transitive dependency on Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE caused by pulling in spring-batch-core 3.0.4.RELEASE.